# Chatbot Language Translation: Saving the Detected Language for Response Translation

Tags: c#, json, chatbot, azure-language-understanding, language-translation

I have a chatbot that is implementing translation middleware. The middleware detects the incoming language and translates the query into English. I have been working to save the detected language as a variable to pass for translating the response into the user's language, but have hit a roadblock.

```
protected override async Task OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext<IMessageActivity> turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            var body = new object[] { new { Text = turnContext.Activity.Text } };
            var requestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body);

            //Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            //Console.WriteLine(requestBody);
            //Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");

            //var languageChoice = "de";
 
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
            {
                //var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com" + "/translate?api-version=3.0" + "&from=" + languageChoice + "&to=" + "en";
                var uri = "https://api.cognitive.microsofttranslator.com" + "/translate?api-version=3.0" + "&to=" + "en";

                request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
                request.RequestUri = new Uri(uri);
                request.Content = new StringContent(requestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", _configuration["TranslatorKey"]);
                request.Headers.Add("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Region", "westus2");
 
                var translatedResponse = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var responseBody = await translatedResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
 
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");

                var translation = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TranslatorResponse[]>(responseBody);
                var detectedLanguage = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DetectLanguage[]>(responseBody);

                var ourResponse = detectedLanguage?.FirstOrDefault()?.DetectedLanguage?.FirstOrDefault()?.Language.ToString();

                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                Console.WriteLine(ourResponse);
                Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                
                //Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                //Console.WriteLine(turnContext.Activity.Text);
                //Console.WriteLine(translation?.FirstOrDefault()?.Translations?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text.ToString());
                //Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                
                // Update the translation field
                turnContext.Activity.Text = translation?.FirstOrDefault()?.Translations?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text.ToString();
            }

            // First, we use the dispatch model to determine which cognitive service (LUIS or QnA) to use.
            var recognizerResult = await _botServices.Dispatch.RecognizeAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);
            
            // Top intent tell us which cognitive service to use.
            var topIntent = recognizerResult.GetTopScoringIntent();
            
            // Next, we call the dispatcher with the top intent.
            // ***** ERROR *****
            await DispatchToTopIntentAsync(turnContext, topIntent.intent, recognizerResult, cancellationToken);
        }
```

Using the console log from responseBody:

```
[{"detectedLanguage":{"language":"es","score":1.0},"translations":[{"text":"Hello","to":"en"}]}]
```

We have determined that responseBody is an Object array that contains an attribute “detectedLanguage”, an object, with the attributes “language” and “score”.
To retrieve the variable “language” from the object “detectedLanguage” we have made the following attempt, using “turnContext.Activity.Text” which is returned as the translated text as an example to follow.

We also added two internal classes that mimic the implementation of “turnContext.Activity.Text”:

1)

```
namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Translation.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Array of translated results from Translator API v3.
    /// </summary>
    internal class TranslatorResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("translations")]
        public IEnumerable<TranslatorResult> Translations { get; set; }
    }
    internal class DetectLanguage
    {
        [JsonProperty("detectedLanguage")]
        public IEnumerable<LanguageResult> DetectedLanguage { get; set; }
    }
}
```

2. 

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Translation.Model
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Translation result from Translator API v3.
    /// </summary>
    internal class TranslatorResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("to")]
        public string To { get; set; }
    }
    internal class LanguageResult
    {
        [JsonProperty("language")]
        public string Language { get; set; }
    }
}
```

However, when we try to test and display “ourResponse” in the console we are met with the following error message:

```
fail: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter[0]
      [OnTurnError] unhandled error : Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Translation.Model.LanguageResult]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
      To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List<T>) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object. 
      Path '[0].detectedLanguage.language', line 1, position 33.
```

We have determined that we are hitting this error because “detectedLanguage” is not an array like “translations” is. (Shown in console output below):

```
[{"detectedLanguage":{"language":"es","score":1.0},"translations":[{"text":"Hello","to":"en"}]}]
```

My question is how do we adjust this implementation to work with the object detectedLanguage outside of an array, or how do we adjust detectedLanguage to be contained within a string to work with the implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Your class structure doesn't match your json.  What you want is the following:

```
internal class DetectedLanguage    
{
    [JsonProperty("language")]
    public string Language { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("score")]
    public double Score { get; set; } 
}

internal class TranslatorResult
{
    [JsonProperty("text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("to")]
    public string To { get; set; }
}

internal class TranslatorResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("detectedLanguage")]
    public DetectedLanguage DetectedLanguage { get; set; } 
    [JsonProperty("translations")]
    public IEnumerable<TranslatorResult> Translations { get; set; } 
}
```

Note how `DetectedLanguage` should be represented as a single object ON the `TranslatorResponse` object, which you are not doing currently.  In addition, the `Language` property of `DetectedLanguage` is also a single property, not a collection.

Comment: I have made the suggested changes and this looks much cleaner, but this did not fix the error message received.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help @David L.